# Your Enemy? No, Only Helpful

Tags: riddle, steganography

> If I fend, I fall.
>    'Tis is true. But
>   
> shoot me and you'll
>   
>  never hit.
>   
>  Only the gentle
>   
> terror of the mist 
>   
> has me under its 
>   
> everlasting doom.
>   
>  Right atop will
>   
> everyone see 
>   
> just a half 
>   
> k actually I'll stop right here. Who am I?

Comment: "its not here jk" :p

Comment: @Mordechai Haha yes. I think the person who downvoted this riddle didn't realize that it was not really [on hold] either.

Comment: If it's not central to the puzzle, may I recommend removing the title suffix? Many people will probably skip right over it.

Comment: haha, +1 for clickbait

Comment: I'd suggest putting normal brackets rather than square brackets here so people know it's not true

Comment: Just curious, is the space after "hold" required by the system to override the usual on hold?

Comment: @feelinferrety yes it is part of the puzzle but I forgot a word! :(

Comment: @Mordechai Yes. It wouldn't let me put that in otherwise.

Comment: I have a suggestion for the title which is more descriptive (if my answer is correct) and doesn't introduce confusion: "Your Enemy? No, Only Helpful."

Comment: @feelinferrety All right I changed it. Thanks for the suggestion! :) I didn't realize the title would cause so much of a backlash.

Comment: It's just that the original utilized a highly recognizable, well-established network standard for low-quality or off-topic questions. It was poor practice to have it there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I solved this yesterday but didn't feel like answering on my phone. I'm surprised nobody else has guessed:

> A bee

If I fend, I fall.

> Bees sting to defend themselves, but for at least some species, the sting comes out along with their insides and they die.

'Tis is true. But
shoot me and you'll
never hit.

> Unless you've got terrific aim and/or luck. Such a tiny, moving target!

Only the gentle
 
terror of the mist
has me under its
everlasting doom.

> To work with bees, keepers will smoke them. It doesn't seem to hurt them, but they do calm down.

Right atop will
everyone see
just a half
k actually I'll stop right here. Who am I?

> The acrostic down says "It's not here. jk" and this last stanza points to the title, which acrostics to "honey" (backwards).